# How to Kill Specific Firefox Profile via Command Line [Java]

Tags: java, firefox, command-line, command

I'd like to close/kill a specific Firefox Profile via command line in Java.

Based on what I read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options) I am able to start any Firefox Profile using this code:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();

Process pr = rt.exec("cmd.exe /c start firefox -P " + profile);
```

This works perfectly.

However, the document also states that there is an option to kill a specific Firefox Profile via the `-kill` command. However, I've tried several different variations and none of them seem to work:

```
rt.exec("cmd.exe /c firefox kill -P " + profile);
rt.exec("cmd.exe /c kill firefox -P " + profile);
rt.exec("cmd.exe /c pkill firefox -P " + profile);
```

The documentation states these "other (command) options need to be documented" but I haven't found any documentation on how to kill a specific profile after searching for hours.

What is the correct syntax/command to use?

I'm using Java on Windows machine.

Thanks

Comment: did you try taskkill?

Comment: @S.K. What is the full command to kill a specific profile?

Comment: I think it will not be possible from taskkill. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28674066/close-multiple-profiles-of-firefox-using-cmd and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13961724/how-to-kill-firefox-gracefully-from-command-line and